# ng-repeat is not updating my mode data

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularJS. I am using ionic framework for android application development. In my project I am calling webservice and getting its response and attaching that response to scope variable to get data on the view. First time webservice called and updates the view as expected but when I call the service again that is not updating my data. It seems as ng-repeat is not working due to some reference loosing problem. But I am not able to find out the solution of that. Although I have tried different solution via using apply() as was mentioned in one of the stack overflow posts. Below is the code of attaching web-service response to the scope variable.

```
 $http(req).then(function (response) {
                  if (response.data.IsSuccess) {
                     console.log("data = " + JSON.stringify(response.data));
                     console.log('Response is '+response.data.IsSuccess);
                     $scope.companies = response.data.Response.Companies;
                  }
```

and below is the line of code using to update the view

```
<div class="col col-100" ng-repeat="company in companies">
```

any help or advice

Below is the login code that is calling webservice to update my data

```
function callLogInService(userName, password){
  console.log("user name is " +userName);
  console.log("password is " + password);

  var req = {
               method: 'POST',
               url: ApiUrl +  '/api/User/LoginUser',
               headers: {
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
               },
               data: {
               Email: userName,
               Password: password
               }
              }

                    $ionicLoading.show({
                        template: 'Signing in...'
                    });

                   $http(req).then(function (response) {
                        if (response.data.IsSuccess) {
                           console.log("data = " + JSON.stringify(response.data));
                           console.log('Response is '+response.data.IsSuccess);
                           var userID = response.data.Response.AppUserId;
                           var userName = response.data.Response.AppUserName;
                           setUserName(userName);
                           setUserId(userID);
                           $rootScope.appUserName;
                           var userIdFromSession = getUserID;
                           if(undefined == $rootScope.companyIdForSubscription
                                    || $rootScope.companyIdForSubscription == 0){
                            console.log("id is undefined for subscription");
                           } else {
                            console.log("company subscription id is " + $rootScope.companyIdForSubscription);
                            $scope.subscribe($rootScope.companyIdForSubscription);
                           }
                           $scope.close();
                           $scope.setVisibilityOdSideMenuIcons();
                           $scope.getAllCompanies();
                        }
                        else {
                          showErrorAlertDialogue(response.data.ErrorMessage);
                        }
                    }, function (reason) {
                    console.log('reason is ' + reason.data);
                    $log.info('reasonf log is' + reason) ;
                        showErrorAlertDialogue("Please check your internet connection.");
                    }).finally(function () {
                        console.log("finally is called");
                        $ionicLoading.hide();
                        $ionicPopup.close()
                    });
}
```

$scope.getAllCompanies(); this line is calling service again

Comment: What is the console output?

Comment: How you are calling service again ?

Comment: in console I can see my updated data which I am getting from server.

Comment: @UmairFarooq: from side menu there is a login button.When login button is clicked a pop up comes up with asking login  credentials.on click login button when I get respose success I call that service again

Comment: Please post that code as well. In which you are calling this service.

Comment: I have updated my code with login function that is responsible of calling my sevice again

Comment: Let us see the error .

Comment: check if you are getting IsSuccess  as true

Comment: yes, i have checked it. IsSuccess is true and in conditional block the console.log () statements are running and printing result on console too.